# ts-mockito mocked promise never resolves

Tags: typescript, ts-mockito

given this

```
beforeAll(() => {
  testContainer.register(Beans.CEC_LOCATION, {
    useFactory: (c) => {
      const contextMock = mock<ContentfulEntryContext<ContentfulLocationFields>>();
      const entryMock = mock<Entry<ContentfulLocationFields>>();
      when(entryMock.fields).thenReturn({
        id: '42',
        name: 'Deep Mind',
      });
      when(contextMock.get()).thenResolve(instance(entryMock));
      const location = (id: string) => {
        return instance(contextMock);
      };
      location('42').get().then((v) => console.log(v));
      return location;
    },
  });
});
```

when `location.get()` is called, `then` never resolves, even on a 60s timeout, reject seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bug in the `ts-mockito` library itself ([issue #191](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito/issues/191)).
A [pull request](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito/pull/194) is on it's way, so hopefully it will be fixed soon.
Currently, at version 2.6.1, it is still there.